# Socket.io + co: Is this how it's supposed to be used?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, co

I am trying to get http://socket.io/ working with [co](https://github.com/tj/co).

I am trying to do some tasks asynchronously in my code.

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    // <--- need to do something heavy here

    socket.on('something', function (data) {

        // <--- need to do something heavy here

    });

    // <--- need to do something heavy here

});
```

That's how socket.io works. I would like to add `co` to the mix now. I've tried the following:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    co(function* () {

        yield something(); // <--- this works

        socket.on('something', function (data) {

            yield something(); // <--- this does not work

        });

        yield something(); // <--- this works
    });
});
```

Get this error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word`

And this:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    co(function* () {

        yield something(); // <--- this works

        socket.on('something', function (data) {

            co(function* () {
                yield something(); // <--- this works
            });

        });

        yield something(); // <--- this works
    });
});
```

My question is, is this how it is supposed to be used, or is ther something I've missed. It seems like an awful lot of extra code to wrap everything?

Comment: you can't have asynchronous logic inside of a generator.

Comment: @KevinB I do have strict mode enabled. Oh ok.

Comment: Have you tried `socket.on('...', co(function *(data) {}));`?

Comment: I don't think `co` would be very useful with a socket event. promises only resolve once, and events happen multiple times. What were you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @KevinB I was trying to make heavy database calls asynchronous somehow!

Comment: @Herku I will try it!

Comment: They should be asynchronous on their own. Most database connectors only allow asynchronous.

Comment: @KevinB I need the rest of the code to wait though, as the code continues before the database retrieves anything (the problem!). I am perhaps utilizing it in a weird way.

Comment: That's what callbacks are for. You can use promises too, but it's no different, just a differently looking syntax.

Comment: @KevinB Exactly what I'm trying to get rid of (callback hell).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90933/discussion-between-kevin-b-and-karl-morrison).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I thought about it again.

```
io.on('connection', co.wrap(function *(socket) {

    yield something();

    socket.on('something', co.wrap(function *(data) {

        yield something();

    }));

    yield something();
}));
```

This should do the Trick. Wrap returns a function, which will return a Promise then. Here we don't care about the latter. 
[Co Documentation On Co.wrap](https://github.com/tj/co#co-v4)

Comment: I'll try it and get back (I totally forgot that I could of used co to pass a generator function DOH)

Comment: Tadamn and it works flawlessly :) Now I just need to learn to write custom promise code and I'm all set for the big world.